Book with a line about morality of building orphanages
There was a book I read several years ago and can't remember much about. I read it as an e-book but I'm pretty sure it was published after 2000. The main detail I can remember is an exchange that goes something like

(The characters discover another character is doing good stuff for shady reasons)
A: So what are we going to do about it?
B: Nothing
A: What do you mean nothing? He's [whatever act is was I can't remember]
B: Yes, and it's got a good outcome. If a man spends his life building orphanages, dedicating everything to building these great buildings, and all the while secretly hates the devil out of orphans, who cares?

